# broken form submit button when styled

Tags: html, css, contact-form

I have a very simple php contact form that works. I am trying to make the form look nice and everything has been smooth until I get to styling the submit button.

The button code is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I would like to use css to style the button.

The code I would like to use is:

```
<input type="submit" id="comment-submit" value="Submit">
```

The CSS for id="comment-submit" is:

```
#comment-submit {
    width: 144px;
    height: 44px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    font-family: "YanoneBold", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    padding: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin: 30px 0 80px 0;
}
```

With no styling the form submits properly. With styling the form does nothing.

Comment: I doubt it is with the styling. Do you have any JavaScript that manipulates `$('#comment-submit')`?

Comment: how is it possible. Style can never change the default functionality of a submit button.

Comment: I'll check the js. I'm pretty sure it is not there but it is possible I missed something

Comment: Can you use the TAB key to select the button and submit that way? If so, I'm guessing it is related to text-shadow/block. If I was you, I'd comment out each part of the CSS individually and check. Then uncomment the last and try the next until you find which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Visual Event may help you in finding if js manipulated your button http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: As William thought there was a JS catching $('#comment-submit')

Comment: @SVS: Using the keyboard, then no this can't ever happen.  I've seen CSS prevent mouse operations many times when z-order and/or negative margins invisibly eclipse buttons with other elements making them unclickable, neither of which are present in this question...

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to a `<button type="submit"` it might work or change the css to `input[type=submit]{}` but that might have issues in IE

Comment: <button type="submit"> is still not a viable candidate for real-world use because of Internet Explorer :(, it works, but all submit buttons on a form are submitted, so the server-side code cannot determine which one was pressed.  <button> is OK for non-form submit buttons, or forms with just the one button though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring it as an `ID`, declare it as a `CLASS`

so

```
.comment_submit {
    width: 144px;
    height: 44px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    font-family: "YanoneBold", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    padding: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin: 30px 0 80px 0;
}

<input type="submit" class="comment_submit" value="Submit">
```

Try this, I guess may be that id is causing problems, and make dash to underscore, and just for the purpose, use a simple font instead of using a web font, and remove text-shadow property too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I should add it in comment but I dont have priviledge.

I copy/paste your example and it works. I have:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="ble" value="uff" />
    <input type="submit" id="comment-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in Chrome and Firefox it sends GET data. Maybe problem is somewhere else. One thing what is different is that your mouse cursor doesn't change.